# I want to authenticate an admin using OAuth2 and access data for accounts that are under this admin

Tags: google-oauth

I want to authenticate an admin using OAuth2 and access data for accounts that are under this admin.
Primarily something like this, I have an organisation : A --> B, C, D where A is the admin.
If i authenticate A can i access data from B,C,D.

We were able to do this in OAuth1.0 and appending email ids in request URL's.
How do we achieve it in OAuth2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(assuming your users are under a Google Apps domain)

This can be achieved in OAuth 2.0 using service accounts. You need to:

1. Create a service accounts and download private key.
2. Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account (see the link below for instructions).
3. Use a signed assertion requesting access to the users data to receive an access token for use in subsequent API calls.

See here for an example using Google Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

See also the "Additional Claims" section here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwtcontents

Comment: DO all google apis support this or is this method limited to a particular set of APIs ?

Comment: I believe this ought to work for all Google APIs that support OAuth 2, but I would suggest trying to be sure - make sure you request (and give permissions for under "Manage third party OAuth Client access" in your domain control panel) the correct scope for the API you are trying to access.